# unexplainable python dict problem

Tags: python, dictionary

hey all,
i been trying to make a class that uses a dictionary to construct a kind of table but something extremely weird is happening.. heres my code

```
class dbase:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rows = {}
        self.cols = {}
    def addrow(self, name):
        self.rows[name] = self.cols
    def addcol(self, name):
        for x in self.rows:
            self.rows[x][name] = None
    def printit(self):
        for x in self.rows:
            print x, self.rows[x]
a = dbase()
a.addrow("coke")
a.addcol("price")
a.printit()
a.addrow("sprite")
a.printit()
```

ok heres the weird thing. my program prints the sprite row as having a inner dictionary with a "price" value but no where in my program did i say self.cols["price"] = None
so howcome the addrow function for sprite puts this inner dictionary into it?
thanks for any help

Comment: Read http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables all `self.rows[x]` refer to the same object `self.cols`.

Comment: "no where in my program did i say `self.cols["price"] = None`" Yes, there is. This one: `self.rows[x][name] = None` says precisely that, since self.rows[x] is set to self.cols previously.

Comment: i dont know why i am finding this so confusing. i thought self.cols will always equal {} (an empty dict) because i never explicitly state self.cols = {"price": None}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every value in `self.rows` is assigned `self.cols`, so they **share** the same dictionary as a key. If you modify `self.rows[x]`, then you also modify `self.rows[y]`, because **they are the same object**. Similarly, if you then re-add `self.cols` as the value for `self.rows[z]`, it has all the same contents, because it's still the same object.

If you wanted to make a separate empty dict for the row each time, then **do that**: assign `{}`.

But you really don't need a class for this in the first place; it's just pushing you into using a custom interface for something that's naturally done directly in Python. You should probably also be looking into `collections.defaultdict`.

Answer (score 4):

Wow. This is the messiest code I've seen in a while. You realize that when you add a row, you're just adding the same dictionary that every other column has.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.rows = {}
    self.cols = {}
def addrow(self, name):
    self.rows[name] = self.cols
```

I think you meant

```
def addrow(self, name):
    self.rows[name] = {}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `a.addcol("price")` the code modifies `self.rows[x][name]`, setting it equal to `None`.

`self.cols` is thus set to equal the dict `{'price': None}`. Since each `self.rows[x]` is set equal to `self.cols`, you get the same dict printed each time.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up the columns for a row, you always refer to `self.cols` - because Python handles this like a reference, anytime that you update it you update it for everything that points to that reference.

You should initialize it to an appropriate value each time if you expect a different set of columns for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You're reusing the same dictionary instance all the time.

```
def addrow(self, name):
    self.rows[name] = self.cols
```

Remember that Python is similar like Java when it comes to variables - each name is just a reference to an object instance. It's not like in C where variable assignment almost always means *copying* the value.

If you want to create a quick-n-dirty table class for rows and columns, you could make use of `defaultdict`, for example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class RowsAndColumns:
    def __init__(self):
        self._rows = defaultdict(dict)

    def get(self, row, col):
        return self._rows[row][col]

    def set(self, row, col, value):
        self._rows[row][col] = value

matrix = RowsAndColumns()
matrix.set("Coke", "Price", 1.99)
print matrix.get("Coke", "Price") # 1.99
print matrix.get("Pepsi", "Price") # KeyError "Price"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to just have a list of dictionaries. Like this:

```
# A new "database"
dbase = []
# Adding a new "row".
dbase.append({})
# Adding columns to a specific row:
dbase[0]['newcol'] = "The value"
# Retrieving a colum from a row which will raise a KeyError if the column doesn't exist:
dbase[0]['newcol']
# Retrieving a colum from a row which will return None if the column doesn't exist:
dbase[0].get('anothercol')
```

Also you could look at the DefaultDict, but I think it's better to learn how standard dictionaries and objects work first.